# Trying to compare IP address's but unfamiliar with the return type

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to take a IP address I get from Scapy, and compare it to a known IP to start another function, when I try to compare part of the code returns a object or something? I'm unsure what exactly it is.

I've tried comparing the out put to a string, and INT, I've printed what I'm trying to compare and its not what I was expecting,

```
def arp_ping():
    ans, unans = srp(Ether(src = "b8:27:eb:a0:57:ff", dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst="172.16.16.0/24"),timeout=2)
    print(ans.summary(lambda p: p[1].sprintf("%Ether.src% is at %ARP.psrc%")))
    print(ARP.psrc)
    if ARP.psrc == "172.16.16.206":
        print("blueberry is %Ether.src% at %ARP.psrc%")
```

output

```
68:ef:bd:8c:07:21 is at 172.16.16.1
60:38:e0:06:4e:2b is at 172.16.16.50
d4:81:d7:e6:b5:5a is at 172.16.16.100
d4:81:d7:e6:b5:e0 is at 172.16.16.101
64:51:06:34:b4:a7 is at 172.16.16.103
8c:dc:d4:2b:ee:7f is at 172.16.16.108
b8:27:eb:a0:57:ff is at 172.16.16.202
b8:27:eb:40:a8:08 is at 172.16.16.203
b8:27:eb:32:83:a0 is at 172.16.16.204
b8:27:eb:e7:46:93 is at 172.16.16.206
b8:27:eb:50:c7:c6 is at 172.16.16.207
b8:27:eb:8b:6a:60 is at 172.16.16.208
None
<Field (ARP).psrc>
```

I am expecting

```
68:ef:bd:8c:07:21 is at 172.16.16.1
60:38:e0:06:4e:2b is at 172.16.16.50
d4:81:d7:e6:b5:5a is at 172.16.16.100
d4:81:d7:e6:b5:e0 is at 172.16.16.101
64:51:06:34:b4:a7 is at 172.16.16.103
8c:dc:d4:2b:ee:7f is at 172.16.16.108
b8:27:eb:a0:57:ff is at 172.16.16.202
b8:27:eb:40:a8:08 is at 172.16.16.203
b8:27:eb:32:83:a0 is at 172.16.16.204
b8:27:eb:e7:46:93 is at 172.16.16.206
b8:27:eb:50:c7:c6 is at 172.16.16.207
b8:27:eb:8b:6a:60 is at 172.16.16.208

None

"blueberry is b8:27:eb:e7:46:93 at 172.16.16.206
```

Comment: What type is that that has an `sprintf` method?

Comment: `Packet` type in scapy

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what package you're using, so I am unable to test this.  However, it looks as though the following will work:

```
def arp_ping():
    ans, unans = srp(Ether(src = "b8:27:eb:a0:57:ff", dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst="172.16.16.0/24"),timeout=2)
    print(ans.summary(lambda p: p[1].sprintf("%Ether.src% is at %ARP.psrc%")))
    print(ARP.psrc)
    if ans.summary(lambda p: p[1].sprintf("%ARP.psrc%")) == "172.16.16.206":
        print(ans.summary(lambda p: p[1].sprintf("blueberry is %Ether.src% at %ARP.psrc%")))
```

Comment: So this didn't work, the output from this gives me the IP addresses in a loop under the mac + ip from the ans arp ping. also, idk what you mean by package but im using scapy with python 3.5

Comment: Your "expected output" in the questions includes "the output from this gives me the IP addresses in a loop under the mac + ip from the ans arp ping"

Is 172.16.16.206 in that list?

Comment: yes, so .206 is present in both the list from the arp ping, and that main list is only a function for debugging, but what was missing from the function you wrote is it just returned a list of Ip addresses, what im trying to do is find the mac associated with a certain ip and return that mac and that mac only so i can pass it on to another function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def arp_ping():
ans, unans = srp(Ether(src = "b8:27:eb:a0:57:ff", dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst="172.16.16.0/24"),timeout=2)
print(ans.nsummary(lambda p: p[1].sprintf("%Ether.src% is at %ARP.psrc%")))
for r in ans.res:
    if r[1].sprintf("%ARP.psrc%") == "172.16.16.206":
        e_src = r[1].sprintf("%Ether.src%")
        a_src = r[1].sprintf("%ARP.psrc%")
        print("blueberry is {0} at {1}".format(e_src, a_src))
```

got me to what i wasnted, idk know why other than i was comparing something that wasnt what i thought it was

```
0000 68:ef:bd:8c:07:21 is at 172.16.16.1
0001 60:38:e0:06:4e:2b is at 172.16.16.50
0002 d4:81:d7:e6:b5:e0 is at 172.16.16.101
0003 d4:81:d7:e6:b5:5a is at 172.16.16.100
0004 64:51:06:34:b4:a7 is at 172.16.16.103
0005 8c:dc:d4:2b:ee:7f is at 172.16.16.108
0006 b8:27:eb:a0:57:ff is at 172.16.16.202
0007 b8:27:eb:40:a8:08 is at 172.16.16.203
0008 b8:27:eb:32:83:a0 is at 172.16.16.204
0009 b8:27:eb:e7:46:93 is at 172.16.16.206
0010 b8:27:eb:43:9c:3e is at 172.16.16.205
0011 b8:27:eb:50:c7:c6 is at 172.16.16.207
0012 b8:27:eb:8b:6a:60 is at 172.16.16.208
None
blueberry is b8:27:eb:e7:46:93 at 172.16.16.206
```